# ansible user module set admin to standard user on osx

Tags: macos, ansible

I have a task which needs to set the user's default shell to zsh, after run, the user will be set from admin user to standard user, thus lose admin privileges. How to fix this??

my osx version: 10.10.5
ansible version: 1.9.2

```
- name: set zsh as default shell
  sudo: yes
  user: name=aaron shell=/usr/local/bin/zsh
  when: ansible_distribution == "MacOSX"
```

Comment: You want the user to have admin privileges?

Comment: no, I'm using my user(admin privilege) run the ansible playbook, but after run, my user becomes a standard user.

Comment: That is the expected. I am not sure what you want. Do you want user 'aaron' to have admin privileges after you run the playbook?

Comment: yes, to be precise, I want my user, aaron, to remain admin after run that task.

Comment: I'm running the ansible playbook locally on my mac machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **group** parameter to set whatever group you want. I think by default it assigns group **staff**

```
user: name=aaron shell=/usr/local/bin/zsh group=admin
```

Comment: I just want to mention that I noticed that the group is set to -1 (nogroup) as default. I am running macOS 10.12.2.